# C# How to check checkboxes from code correctly?

Tags: c#, forms, checkbox, visual-studio-2015

I try to check some checkboxes in a settings form from code.
When the form opens, the setting values are correct, but the checkbockes do not take that value over correctly.
Only the first checkbox, which gets the TRUE value, will be checked. All the following checkboxes remain unchecked. Am I missing any porperties here?

[values submitted to settings form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj49R.jpg)

[checkboxes in settings form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xch3n.jpg)

This is what I do in my settings form:

```
public Form_settings(MySettings settings)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    tmpSettings = settings;

    [...]

    MessageBox.Show(tmpSettings.tab1.ToString() + "\r\n" + tmpSettings.tab2.ToString() + "\r\n" + tmpSettings.tab3.ToString() + "\r\n" + tmpSettings.tab4.ToString() + "\r\n" + tmpSettings.tab5.ToString());

    checkBox_settings_modul1.Checked = tmpSettings.tab1;
    checkBox_settings_modul2.Checked = tmpSettings.tab2;
    checkBox_settings_modul3.Checked = tmpSettings.tab3;
    checkBox_settings_modul4.Checked = tmpSettings.tab4;
    checkBox_settings_modul5.Checked = tmpSettings.tab5;
}
```

The way I open the settings form:

```
Form_settings settingsForm = new FormSettings(settings);
settingsForm.ShowDialog();
settings = settingsForm.tmpSettings;
```

Comment: If I submit the values: false,true,true,true,true. Only checkbox 2 is checked

Comment: If you directly set all 5 to `true`, are they checked?

Comment: Yes, they are all checked then.

Comment: ok, what if you set them to  `settings.tab1`, etc. instead of `tmpSettings.tab1` - are they checked correctly?

Comment: No, they are not... but if I put a messagebox after the first `checkbox.checked = ...` to check the second value of tmpSettings, it is false!

Comment: can you please post code for `MySettings` class (or struct)?

Comment: the problem is clearly not the checkbox, it is the value in the tmpSetting, can you add a breakpoint and look what happens with the tab1 - 5 value, could be an other process changing the value

Comment: If I do it like this, it works for all 5 checkboxes: `bool tab1 = settings.tab1; checkbox1.checked = tab1;` but: WHY?

Comment: `MySettings` only has som props, strings and bools, like `public bool tab1 { get; set; }`

Comment: @Quen something in your code is modifying `settings`. I can't tell without seeing all of your code that references `settings`, or `tmpSettings`. Btw, why do you need `tmpSettings`, which appears to be a public field or property in `settingsForm`? It's an unusual setup...